# Adapting a Kaldi model not recognizing words

Tags: speech, kaldi

I began using Kaldi to train a model for use with VOSK in python.  The issue i am experiencing is with recognizing certain words such as "manor".  I have tried adding multiple variation in the lexicon file such as

M AE N ER

M AE N AO

M AE N AA

M AE N AH

The issue still remains that if i recite manor it detects it as "man or" or "man a" instead of "manor".  Im confused as to where this is coming from and how i can guide kaldi into detecting it the way i expect.